# Linking external headers file in ROS package

Tags: ros, catkin-make, cmake, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the Kilobot simulator [Kilombo](https://github.com/JIC-CSB/kilombo) with a ROS package. I am installing Kilombo as normal as a system library. I am then trying to include the Kilombo header file inside the ROS package to create a Kilombo simulation. The CMakeLists.txt of Kilombo looks like this:

```
add_library(sim display.c skilobot.c kbapi.c params.c stateio.c runsim.c neighbors.c distribution.c gfx/SDL_framerate.c gfx/SDL_gfxPrimitives.c gfx/SDL_gfxBlitFunc.c gfx/SDL_rotozoom.c)

add_library(headless skilobot.c kbapi.c params.c stateio.c runsim.c neighbors.c distribution.c)
set_target_properties(headless PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "SKILO_HEADLESS")

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    add_definitions(-std=c99)
    add_definitions("-Wall -O2 -g")
#    add_definitions("-Wall -O3 -march=native -g")  
endif()

INSTALL(TARGETS sim headless
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)

INSTALL(FILES kilombo.h DESTINATION include)

INSTALL(FILES kilolib.h message.h message_crc.h params.h skilobot.h
    DESTINATION include/kilombo)

add_subdirectory(tests)
```

The CMakeLists.txt of the ROS package I am creating looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(Kilombo_test)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp std_msgs)
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    add_definitions(-std=c99)
    add_definitions("-Wall -O2 -g")
endif()
include_directories(/usr/local/include /usr/local/lib)
link_directories(/usr/local/include)
add_executable(generated_test orbit.c)
target_link_libraries(generated_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I include the Kilombo header files just as normal: `#include <kilombo.h>`

However, when I run catkin_make, I get many "undefined reference" errors. Some of those messages are:

```
orbit.c:53 undefined reference to 'kilo_turn_left'
orbit.c:53 undefined reference to 'set_motors'
```

These messages are shown after the commands:

```
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/viki/catkin_ws/build"
####
Linking C executable generated_test
```

Both, `kilo_turn_left` and the function `set_motors` is defined in "kilolib.h" which itself is included in "kilombo.h".

Everything works fine if try running the simulation normally and not as a ROS package. The Makefile when I try to run it normally looks like the following. I have removed the parts which compiled for the real bot and not for the simulation.

```
SOURCES=orbit.c 
EXECUTABLE=orbit

# path of kilombo.h distributed with the simulator but also needed
# when compiling the user program for the real kilobot (avr-gcc has different default paths)
SIMHEADERS=/usr/local/include

#path to kilolib.a in the official kilolib, needed for real bots only
KILOLIB    =$(KILOHEADERS)/build/kilolib.a

SIM_CFLAGS = -c -g -O2 -Wall -std=c99  

SIM_LFLAGS = -lsim -lSDL -lm -ljansson
sim: $(EXECUTABLE)
hex: $(EXECUTABLE).hex
all: sim hex

clean :
    rm *.o $(EXECUTABLE) *.elf *.hex
```

However, when running a simulation as a ROS package, we need to define a CMakeLists.txt which is what I am having trouble with. What exactly am I doing wrong? I know there are many similar questions on this board but I have not been able to find a solution to my problem in those questions (though I believe I have gotten closer to the solution)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270328/linking-external-headers-file-in-ros-package/) by [rabee](https://answers.ros.org/users/31806/rabee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a *linking* problem (ie: libraries), not a problem with headers.

> ```
> add_executable(generated_test orbit.c)
> ```

```
target_link_libraries(generated_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

You're not linking any of the kilo* libraries, which is why the compiler cannot resolve the symbols.

You'll have to add one (or both? I don't know these libraries) of the `sim` or `headless` libs to the `target_link_library(..)` statement that you already have.

---

However: note that you are compiling C here: ROS has no client library for C, so you'll have to write something in C++. If/when you do, know that C++ mangles names, so you'll have to take care of that as well. You should get sufficient results if you search for `c++ link c library` with your favourite search engine.

---

Edit: some suggestions / questions:

- `/usr/local/lib` should already be on the link path, and `/usr/local/include` should already be on the include path, so I don't believe you need to add those
- putting `/usr/local/include` on the linker path seems rather strange to me: do you have libraries in that directory?
- the same for `/usr/local/lib` on the include path: headers in a lib dir?
- `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX` is set if the compiler is `g++`, but `-std=c99` is something for the C compiler. Should that be `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUC` in the conditional?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-06**:
Note btw that this is not a ROS problem, but really a missing statement in your CMake file.

**Comment by [rabee](https://answers.ros.org/users/31806/rabee/) on 2017-09-06**:
Then perhaps you coudl answer here ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023578/linking-external-headers-file-in-ros-package?noredirect=1#comment79127250_46023578

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-06**:
No, I won't. And this is a classic example of why you should avoid cross-posting questions like this. It leads exactly to this sort of duplicated effort. You've basically now received the same answer twice, in two different places ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-06**:
And additionally: this question has been asked multiple times already. Please use the search before asking new questions. See #q227146 and #q200205 fi.

**Comment by [rabee](https://answers.ros.org/users/31806/rabee/) on 2017-09-06**:
I didn't receive any answers on that question. Which led me to think that perhaps it was a ROS-specific problem which is why I didn't receive any answers on stackoverflow. Which is why I posted here - after a significant wait on the other question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-06**:
You're right, I'd missed the `sept 3` posting date. My apologies. But even then, linking back to your other question and adding the "I think this is something specific to ROS, because .." would be good.

**Comment by [rabee](https://answers.ros.org/users/31806/rabee/) on 2017-09-06**:
No worries. Will do so.
As to your suggestions:

1. Yes, those are superfluous, removing them had no effect
2. Again, not needed.
3. Once again, not needed.
4. Correct, fixed it.

As you pointed out, I needed to add the libraries in the in the target_link_library... statement. Thank you.